# XML Errors in the Task scheduler

Tags: windows-8, scheduled-tasks

When I open the task scheduler I get a pop up telling me that the XML code contains an incorrect value, badly formatted, out of bounds or a bad node.

I get this error for the following tasks:

- VerifiedPublisherCertStoreCheck
- UserTask
- SystemTask
- Consolidator
- Background Synchronization
- HiveUploadTask

When I run `Get-ScheduledTask` in PowerShell I get this output:

```
Get-ScheduledTask : Le code XML de la tâche contient un noud inattendu.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Get-ScheduledTask
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft...T_ScheduledTask) [Get-ScheduledTask], CimException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041316,Get-ScheduledTask
```

The first line is about a not expected node in the XML code.

I'm running Windows 8 Pro 64bits and I didn't get a power outage or have to hard reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Open the [Install.wim of your Windows 8 DVD with 7zip and extract the corrupted task](http://blog.nirsoft.net/2009/09/17/how-to-extract-missing-system-files-from-the-dvd-of-windows-7vista/) to your HDD in C:\Temp.

Now add XML extension to all tasks, run task scheduler, delete the corrupted tasks and import the task again by selecting the extracted XML files.

Comment: The tasks that are faulty don't appear in the task scheduler, and deleting the files in `%windir%\system32\Tasks` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: have you imported the XML files?

Comment: When I import for example the VerifiedPublisherCertStoreCheck I get an error about incorrect format: (35,26):Duration:PT0S

Comment: for me line 35 is this: **<AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>**

Comment: If you're running Windows 8, is it possible for you to upload the contents of the `%windir%\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows` or just the files listed in the OP, I may be able to just replace the faulty files since the ones on the install disc are different (even for working files).

Comment: when you extract the files from the Win8 DVD, the files should be ok. Those files should be better than mine.

Comment: I had the same issue recently / ended up having to delete the tasks via the filesystem as couldn't get the import to work (even after deleting the original and attempting with the same task exported from another machine as well as trying various tweaked copies of the local task's xml.  The tasks in question weren't important (e.g. Customer Experience Improvement), so deleting them was OK / resolved the PowerShell function's issue and prevented errors showing when opening task scheduler.

Comment: NB: After having done the above though, I spotted this which claims to work (sadly I no longer have the corrupt tasks to test this / confirm): http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/19/repair-tasks-task-image-corrupt/